# K3 surfaces with no −2 curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms, k3-surfaces

I seem to remember that a K3 surface with big Picard rank always
has smooth rational curves.

This question is equivalent to the following question about integral quadratic lattices. Let us call a vector in a lattice ($-2$)-vector if its square is $-2$. Consider a primitive, non-degenerate, indefinite lattice in $H^2(K3, {\Bbb Z})$, which has rank $\geq d$. Does it follow that it always has integer ($-2$)-vectors? I think I can prove that there  exists an indefinite sublattice of rank $11$ which has no ($-2$)-vectors. Is it true that an indefinite  sublattice of rank $>11$  always has ($-2$)-vectors? Is there any sharp bound on ranks of sublattices not admitting ($-2$)-vectors? I would be very grateful for any answers or references to papers where something similar was considered.

Comment: What is $d$ in "which has rank $\ge d$"?

Comment: the question is, for which $d$ we can be sure there are no -2 vectors? What about $d=12$? What about $d=20$?

Comment: @MishaVerbitsky: pardon my ignorance, but why does the second question imply the first?

Comment: Did you look at McMullen’s nonprojective K3 surfaces associated to Salem numbers?  I will look now to see their ranks . . .

Comment: . . . The rank is zero.

Comment: For projective K3s, there are -2 curves whenever the Picard rank is at least 12. See, for example, Huybrechts's Lectures on K3 surfaces, Chapter 14, Corollary 3.8.

Comment: Jason: for McMullen's nonprojective K3 surfaces, the Picard lattice is either degenerate or negative definite, and such lattices are easy to construct in any rank.

Comment: Samir: many thanks, this is what I need I think.

Comment: Marco: any smooth rational curve on K3 has square -2. Conversely, using Riemann-Roch, you can prove that any line bundle $L$ with $c_1^2=-2$ satisfies $H^2(L)\neq 0$ or $H^2(L^*)'\neq 0$, and the zero divisor of its section contains a smooth rational curve as a component

Comment: What is meant by $H^2(K3,\mathbb{Z})$? do you mean $H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ for some K3 surface $S$?

Comment: @YCor yes, take any K3 surface. The second cohomology with the intersection product is isomorphic as a lattice to E8^2 + U(-2)^3 for any K3 surface.